# How to add the values of each array in perl?

Tags: perl

Add the elements of each array how can it.?

```
@a1 = (1..5);
@a2 = (1..3);
@a3 = (1..4);
@tar = ("@a1", "@a2", "@a3");
foreach $each(@tar){
        @ar = split(' ',$each);
        foreach $eac(@ar){
        $tot+=$eac;
        }
print "$each total is: $tot\n";
}
```

In this bit of code gives output but the succeeding total value is add with preceding total value. But is I expect the outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 total is: 15
1 2 3 total is: 6
1 2 3 4 total is: 10
```

Comment: `use List::Util 'sum'; ... my $total = sum @ar;`

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;` (though it won't help with this particular problem).

Comment: The question has already been answered, but you can simplify a little by making @tar be an array of arrays instead of an array of strings: `my @tar = (\@a1, \@a2, \@a3);`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are using same variable $tot in each foreach loop. So it retains the old value. Simple fix is to define the $tot as lexical variable in first for each loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@a1 = (1..5);
@a2 = (1..3);
@a3 = (1..4);
@tar = ("@a1", "@a2", "@a3");
foreach $each(@tar){
        my $tot;
        @ar = split(' ',$each);
        foreach $eac(@ar){
        $tot+=$eac;
        }
print "$each total is: $tot\n";
}
```

Output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 total is: 15
1 2 3 total is: 6
1 2 3 4 total is: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want $tot's scope to be just inside the loop, just declare it inside the loop:

```
for $each (@tar) {
    my $tot;
```

Comment: Thank you @choroba abd giw how it is done.? what is the meaning of 'my'. When declare use warnings use strict then only declare the 'my'

Comment: @RPbu: `my` creates a new variable for each iteration of the loop. See [my](http://p3rl.org/my).

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  No exceptions
2. Always declare your variables with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) and use the smallest scope possible.
3. Study [perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for alternative ways of working with arrays and array references.

These changes will clean up your script to the followign:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a1 = (1..5);
my @a2 = (1..3);
my @a3 = (1..4);

my @AoA = (\@a1, \@a2, \@a3);

for my $arrayref (@AoA){
    my $total = 0;
    for my $val (@$arrayref) {
        $total += $val;
    }
    print "@$arrayref total is: $total\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 total is: 15
1 2 3 total is: 6
1 2 3 4 total is: 10
```